# How to get double click event on a picturebox with video streaming

Tags: c#, video, picturebox

Background.
I have a very simple picture box on which I am streaming video using expression encoder sdk 4.

Problem: 
I am unable to get a double click event on it.

```
 deviceSource.PreviewWindow = new PreviewWindow(new HandleRef(PicBox, PicBox.Handle));
   PicBox.MouseDoubleClick  += new System.EventHandler(this.PicBox_DoubleClick);

private void PicBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {MessageBox.Show("");
        }
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what event you wish the DoubleClick function to be called for

```
PicBox += new System.EventHandler(this.PicBox_DoubleClick);
```

Should be

```
PicBox.MouseDoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.PicBox_DoubleClick);
```

Comment: am so sorry. I missed the MouseDoubleClick while copy pasting. It is there.